# cannot resolve method ' requestLocationUpdate' when i call LocationManger

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, import

i'm trying to use `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);`

but i get an error says that:
[image]

i thought it might comes from wrong `LocationListerner` Library  but here is all my imported library

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ahmed.mob_review.MainActivity;
import com.example.ahmed.mob_review.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

**EDITED**

i think it comes from the last parameters `this` [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, (LocationListener) this);
```

Comment: `cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener`

Comment: Make sure that your activity implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener   not android.location.LocationListener..

Answer (score 1):

**Solved** :

- Activity should Implement from `LocationListener`
- I'v to cast `this` activity to `LocationListener`
- `onLocationChanged` won't be called until i request `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER`

**As:**

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
```

now it worked :)